# How do I get rid of the last comma?

Tags: c, arrays, loops

```
   int main(){
   int
      i,
      number[50],
      num;
   printf("Please enter a number:\n");
   scanf("%d", &num);
   for (i = 0; i < num; i++){
   printf("%d: ", i+1);
   scanf("%d", &number[i]);
   }

   printf("You've entered: ");
   for (i = 0; i < num; i++){
      printf("%d, ", number[i]);

   }
   }
```

If I type in 5 randon numbers like below, I can't seem to get this output:

"Please enter a number: 
You've entered: 1, 2, 32, 44 and 45"

Comment: Print the first, then if there are more, print ", " followed by the number

Comment: Figure out how you would do it on a sheet of paper and code that. This is the first number, so I don't need a comma. This is the second number so I do need a comma. this is the last number, so I need "and" instead of a comma...

Comment: I get it. But how do I know when the loop reaches the last number?

Comment: The look goes until i < num. So the last time is when i == num - 1. Better still, deal with the first number (no comma), loop over second to second last number (need preceding comma), then deal with the last number (needs preceding "and)

Comment: I'll give it a try. It's ok without `\n`, but what if I need to go to a new line? Where should I put it?

Comment: before this line: for (i = 0; i < num; i++){ the code needs to check that num is < 50, to avoid a possible overrun of the number[] array

Comment: you know when you are at the last number because the loop counter (i) == (num = 2)

Comment: the returned value from all I/O operations needs to be checked to assure the operation was successful.  On the calls to scanf(), in this code, the check would be: if( 1 != scanf(" %d", &number[i]) ) { // handle error and exit } // implied else, scanf successful ...  notice the leading ' ' in the format string, so leading white space (like a newline) are consumed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("You've entered: ");
for (i = 0; i < num; i++){
   if(num > 1 && i == num-1)
       printf(" and ");
   else if(i)
       printf(", ");
   printf("%d", number[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't know where to put `\n` when I type in 2 numbers.

Comment: @UserFriendly Put `printf("\n");` after the for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your final for loop as below:

```
printf("You've entered: ");
for(i=0;i<num-2;i++)
  printf("%d",number[i]);
printf("%d and %d\n",number[i],number[i+1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. if I want to prompt the user with ordinal numbers: `1st number:` `2nd number:` `3rd number:``..`, what could be the right approach?

Comment: I presume you mean 1st number-23 ,2nd number -22 etc in the output.. then you just need to change the for loop and the printf statement : for loop: for(i=0;i<num;i++) printf("\n The %d number:%d",i+1,number[i]);

Comment: If you are very specifc about the way the output is called as in 1st instead of 1 then use a switch case inside the for loop. So for each input use switch on i i.e switch(i){ case 1: printf("1st number:%d:",number[i]) break; ..... so forth for the length or number of elements of the array }

Comment: just to add a tip .. if you have larger array doesn't make sense to use  n cases .. rather group them by the  way the numbers are pronounced i.e. 1'st', 2'nd', 3'rd',4-20: end with 'th' 4th , 5th etc etc.. so group them all under one case

Answer (score 0):

```
   printf("You've entered: ");
   for (i = 0; i < num; i++){
      printf("%d%s", number[i], (i == num-1) ? "" : ",");

   }
```